# how to send a file in the request after uploading in the react?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, file-upload

```
<form id="uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label className="col-sm-5 form-control-label " for="file">Select a 
file</label>
<div className="col-sm-7">
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
</div>
</form>
```

In the jsx i am passing encType.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("id", idForUpload);
formData.append("uploadFiles", $('#uploadFile')[0]);
ContractAction._uploadFileToContract(formData);
```

i want to pass the id and uploadFiles as key and value i need to pass the file.but i am able to get id but uploadFiles is not coming in the request

and i am making the ajax like below

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import BASEURL from './urlConfig.jsx';
 //import dispatcher from "../dispatchers/dispatcher";

module.exports ={

_callAPI: function(url,method,data,target){

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: (data,textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            target('success', data);   

        },
        error: (jqXhr,textStatus,error) => {
            target('error',jqXhr,textStatus,error);
            console.log("error inside code", jqXhr,textStatus,error);
        },

    });
},

 }
```

Comment: I don't think you can get your files calling `$('#uploadFile')[0]`.

Comment: how to get the file, any other solution

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you'd need to read the file's content and then pass it along.

```
var file = $('#uploadFile')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
    var content = e.target.result;
    console.log(content);
}
reader.readAsText(file);
```

You may want to lookup FileAPI FileReader

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications